# How does well-definedness extend to n-ary operations?

Tags: functions

I know for a $1$-ary map $f: G \rightarrow G$ is well-defined if for all $g, h \in G$ we have $g = h$ implies $f(g) = f(h)$. How is this definition extended for binary and in general, n-ary maps?

Comment: Exactly the same way! $g=(g_1, g_2,..., g_n) = (h_1, h_2,..., h_n)=h$ implies $f(g)=f(h)$.

Comment: This also has nothing inherent to do with groups. A function is well-defined if $x=y$ implies $f(x)=f(y)$. This is true for any function on any set.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically, an $n$-ary map from $X$ to $Y$ takes $n$ arguments from $X$ as input and gives you one argument in $Y$ as output. So it is the same as a function from
$X^n:=X\times\cdots\times X$ to $Y$. In this sense an $n$-ary map is just an ordinary map on a bigger domain. And for ordinary maps you know what well-definedness means.